# Laravel RESTful Controller

Tags: rest, laravel, methods, show

I am new to Laravel and would be great if anybody could answer my below query.

For triggering a show method in RESTful controller, I have created view with the code as 
{!! Form::select('fnd_id', $funds, null) !!}

$funds contains the id and name of the fund and has 3 rows in the database.

Requirement - 
1. How to capture the user selection (from the select dropdown) value, and navigate to the show method with the user selected fund id. ?

Advance apologies if this seems to be a silly/elementary question, but this was the last resort since I;ve been struggling for the past 4 hours on this.

Comment: Remember, the laravel documentation is your friend: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

Comment: Also, for good measure, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I am unable to retrieve the user selected choice from the form::select.. It would be very helpful if you could give me some lead on that..

Comment: `$request->input('selectName');` with the `Request` facade

Comment: Thanks very much, although still struggling :(

Comment: I strongly suggest you read through the documentation. Everything is there.

Comment: Oh sure, I totallly appreciate your help and I shall go through the same. In fact, I am right now doing the same. Thanks there !!

Comment: How have you gotten on with this @lara? I'd be happy to post an answer with a run through of how to do this if you haven't figured it out yet?

Comment: Hello James, I would totally appreciate that. I haven't yet figured out the exact solution yet.